# Simple c function, segfaults on free

Tags: c

I know this has been asked quite a bit, but every example I looked at never seemed to fit exactly.  In the code below if I keep the `free()`, the resulting compiled binary segfaults.  If I remove it, the code works just fine.  My question is, why?

```
int convertTimeToStr(time_t* seconds, char* str)
{
    int rc = 0;

    if (str == NULL) {
        printf("The passed in char array was null!\n");
        rc = 1;
    } else {
        char* buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));

        buf = asctime(gmtime(seconds));
        strcpy(str, buf);

        free(buf);
    }

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code with embedded line numbers :(

Comment: change `memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));` to `memset(buf, '\0', 100*sizeof(char));`

Comment: `sizeof(buf)` is the same as `sizeof(char*)` and is 8 on my machine

Comment: What is the idea behind doing `buf = asctime(gmtime(seconds));` when just before allocating something to `buf`?

Comment: I keep falling into bad habits of assignment (my primary lingua franca is perl).

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  So this line: `char* buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);`  would be better written as: `char* buf = malloc( 100 );`

Comment: this line: `memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));` has the problem that `buf` is a pointer, so will only set 4 (32 bit architecture) or 8 (64 bit architecture) bytes.  Suggest: `memset(buf, '\0', 100));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you *reassign* the pointer to your allocated memory. What you're doing is basically equivalent to

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
a = b;
```

and then wondering why `a` is no longer equal to `5`.

With the assignment `buf = asctime(gmtime(seconds))` you lose the original pointer and have a memory leak.

What the [`asctime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/asctime) function returns is a pointer to a static internal buffer, it's not something you should pass to `free`.

Comment: So the appropriate bit then would be to forgo the whole buf portion and instead do
    strcpy(str, asctime(gmtime(seconds)));
Correct?

Comment: @vergessen Yep, that's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be surprised by that, since you've changed the value of the pointer `buf` from what `malloc()` returned.

```
char* buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);  // value returned by malloc()
memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
buf = asctime(gmtime(seconds));          // change value of buf
strcpy(str, buf);
free(buf);                               // buf differs from above
```

Calling `free()` with an argument that was not returned from `malloc()` (or calling it for the second time) is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you... I would love to mark all of these as an answer as they all help in the larger picture (at least, to help my understanding in c).

Answer (score 1):

You call `malloc` and `memset`, which allocates a buffer and sets it to zeroes, but then you overwrite the value of `buf` with the return value from `asctime`. By the time you call `free`, it is on the return value from `asctime`, not your original allocation. This has three issues:

1. You never use the buffer you allocated with `malloc` for any useful purpose, so you don't need that `malloc` nor the `memset`
2. You lose the pointer returned by `malloc` so you can never `free` it. Your process has leaked memory.
3. You try to `free` the return value from asctime. The return value from asctime does not need to be freed and should not be freed. This causes undefined behavior, in your case a segfault.